# python Dict operation for flask

Tags: python

how to add (sum) all the pnl values of the dictionaries with the same date

from this `[{'pnl': 10, 'date': 2}, {'pnl': 30, 'date': 2}, {'pnl': 20, 'date': 3}]`

To this `[{'pnl': 40, 'date': 2}, {'pnl': 20, 'date': 3}]`

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: I edited the code take a look @Goku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so?

```
pnl_list = [{'pnl': 10, 'date': 2}, {'pnl': 30, 'date': 2}, {'pnl': 20, 'date': 3}]

result = {}
for dictionary in pnl_list:
    date = dictionary['date']
    if date not in result:
        result[date] = dictionary['pnl']
    else:
        result[date] += dictionary['pnl']

summed_pnl = [{'pnl':result[date], 'date':date} for date in result]


#print(summed_pnl) #| [{'pnl': 40, 'date': 2}, {'pnl': 20, 'date': 3}]
```